# вывод видео c++

Tags: c++

всем дарова проблема в выводе видео в консольном приложение на c++  нужно самое простое решение по типу вызов плеера и и воспроизведении заранее подготовленного видео

пробовал ffmpeg но проблемно и много

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скачайте исходники vlc player, посмотрите как там сделано.

Comment: Собственно, vlc-плеер как раз можно запускать из консоли. У него там флажками можно убрать рамку окна, и включить управление воспроизведением через сокет (можно будет отправлять текстовые команды).